# Создание бота на Javascript

Tags: node.js, бот, javascript

Нужно написать бота, который будет заходить на сайт, заполнять некоторые формы и скачивать информацию с сайта. До этого никогда не писал ботов и вообще не представляю как это работает. На сервере используется Node.js и хотелось бы писать бота на js. Подскажите c чего начать и где искать информацию (по каким запросам в гугле)?

Comment: [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) — автоматизация браузеров

Comment: @sergiks ТС не пишет automation тесты, ТС пишет бота...

Comment: @AlexWindHope ТС пишет вопрос, потому, что не знает пока как подступиться к написанию бота )
Selenium вполне оправданный подход к задаче автоматизации заполнения форм и скачивания инфы.

Comment: @sergiks, тогда уж лучше [casper.js](http://casperjs.org/)

Comment: @AlexWindHope casper.js выглядит очень интересно, кажется это как раз то, что я искал. Спасибо. Есть ли возможность автоматически запускать скрипт время от времени? Точнее, чтоб сервер сам запускал скрипт, в зависимости от каких-то условий.

Comment: Ну а в этом вам уже может помочь node.js,

 - http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_process_spawn_command_args_options
 - http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

btw внутри phantom.js есть свой http модуль, но я крайне не рекомендую его использовать в связи с его крайней не стабильностью и не предсказуемостью.

Answer (score 5):

Нужно понять, что будет имитировать бот:

- какой-то запрос на сайт
- парсинг ответа
- следующий запрос, если таковой нужен

Читаем: [http.request(options, callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

В итоге запрос выглядит примерно так:

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

В общем тут ничего сложного, задавайте вопросы, если какие-либо возникнут. Но прежде сами пробуйте их решить.